# How to get ajax request in php?

Tags: php, ajax

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Check_Country.php",
        data: "{Country_name: "+Country_name+"}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(html){
            $('select#Section').empty();
            $('select#Section').append('<option>Select</option>');
            $('select#Section').append(html);
        }
    });
```

How do you detect Country_name in Check_Country.php file?
I am using

```
$_POST['Country_name'];
```

in php file but, the console says that it cannot find `Country_name`.

Comment: how are you getting value of `Country_name` in ajax code ? where is it coming from, show some more `HTML` or `javascript`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

```
data: "{Country_name: "+Country_name"}"
```

instead of

```
data: "{Country_name: "+Country_name+"}"
```

i.e. remove the trailing `+` sign.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but, that way it would be a syntax error.

Comment: use:- data: {Country_name:Country_name}

Answer (score 0):

In your code only one syntax is wrong
you have to change this code :-

```
data: "{Country_name: "+Country_name+"}",
```

into

```
data: {"Country_name": Country_name}
or 
data:   "Country_name="+Country_name,
```

please try this:-

Comment: I got this>>  Notice: Undefined index: Country_name in <filename> on <line number>

Comment: ok,                                                                                                                              then you please define this value like                                                                 var Country_name = " " ; in global